# What are the currents and the power dissipated by the load \$R_{T}\$ in the following circuit

Tags: power, kirchhoffs-laws, voltage-source

[image: Circuit design]

The circuit has 2 voltage sources one of which is 0.5U<sub>R2</sub>, one current source, resistor elements R<sub>1</sub> & R<sub>2</sub>, the load is R<sub>T</sub> 10 ohms.

Having the following circuit, I have used the Kirchhoff's circuit laws to find the current I<sub>1</sub>, which is equal to (1-05*U<sub>R2</sub>)/35.

[image: Solution]

I am stuck here. How should I proceed?

---

After finding out that R<sub>2</sub> is not a linear element and that U<sub>R<sub>2</sub></sub> = 2I<sub>1</sub>*3 ohms, the solution I got to is the following:

[image: The final solution]

Comment: The circuit symbols used are not entirely compliant with the standard ones and this can be misleading.

Comment: @Franc I undestand you but I am unable to change the design. We're using a diffirent standard. If you have particular questions which symbol represents what I could answer them.

Comment: Why do you say that R2 is a non-linear element?

Comment: @G36 Because of the + and - signs beside U(R2), is it not?

Comment: No, R2 is just an ordinary linear resistor. The polarity markings on R2 resistor refers to the "positive" voltage generated by a voltage controlled voltage source 0.5xUR2. And this dependent voltage source is controlled by the voltage drop across R2 resistor.

Comment: Also notice that U_R2 = 2I_1 x 3Ω

Comment: Did you manage to solve it using my tip?   $$U_{R_2} = 2\:I_1 \:3\Omega$$
$$I_1 = \frac{1V - 0.5U_{R_2}}{35\Omega} = \frac{1V - 0.5( 2\:I_1 \:3\Omega)}{35\Omega} $$ Because you are very close to get the solution.

Comment: @G36  I think I managed to solve it thanks to your help. I will upload a picture of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Topological study of the network. From this analysis, obtain the branch voltages, currents and powers using the node voltage method:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Instead, if we set Vg2=-0.5VR2, the currents and voltages take on different values, what will be the right solution?:
[image]

Comment: How can this provide any help to the TS? Is this a solution or what?

Comment: @G36 What I carried out is the study of the network based on the rules of electrical engineering which is based on the topology of electrical networks. It serves to give an idea of how to do a serious study of the network and that ultimately all electrical network simulators use. Maybe you are not interested but it may be of interest to the requesting user.

Comment: @G36 Since this is a work based on my experience in this regard, it may not be free from errors.

Comment: OK, but your answer seems to be wrong. If I do for example a quick nodal analysis I'm getting that the voltage at node 2 is 0.868421V.

Comment: It would be very helpful to know what causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Editing my answer because I see two solutions depending on how the non-standard voltage source symbol is interpreted for voltage polarity.

To G36, I believe that current flowing out of positive terminal is *in most cases* negative, but not necessarily *defined* as negative.

[image: two solutions]

---

Both solutions in spice:

solution 1
[image: solution 1]

solution 2
[image: solution 2]

Comment: But this is not the correct solution.

Comment: I1 can't equal 1/38. Then KVL equation won't hold true.

Comment: Why do you think that KVL will not hold true?

Comment: made a rounding error, it does hold true, my bad

Comment: Also, in your CCCS (F1) in LTspice should have V1 -2. Because the current that is flowing out from the positive terminal of a V1 source is negative by definition.

Comment: Take a look here: https://ltwiki.org/files/LTSpiceSupplementalDocumentation.pdf  ". VNAM is the
name of a voltage source through which the controlling current flows. The
direction of positive controlling current flow is from the positive node,
through the source, to the negative node of VNAM"

Comment: Thank you for the link. In both updated solutions, I have defined current directions going into each voltage source, from positive to negative (so VNAM parameter should not need a sign change).